# creating a local database in a C#

Tags: c#, database

I am writing a C# application

It is an offline test application

It imports a large data file in the form of a .csv file

This file is chosen by the user using a form

I then want to store the information contained in this .csv file in the form of a local database such that I can perform sql queries

I am using Visual Studio 2012

I have never setup an sql database before and only have limited experience using sql on existing databases

My attempt so far is:

1. Solution explorer > Add new file > Local Database (.sdf file)
2. Database Explorer > Tables > Create Table
3. I have then added column names for all the fields setting one as my primary key
4. I have attempted to add a single dataset to my data table with no luck

`string dbfile = new System.IO.FileInfo(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location).DirectoryName + "\\MyDatabase.sdf";
    SqlCeConnection sqlConnection = new SqlCeConnection("datasource=" + dbfile);`

```
SqlCeDataAdapter sqlAdapter = new SqlCeDataAdapter("select * from MyTable", sqlConnection);
AMCCoreSignalsDBDataSet sqlData = new AMCCoreSignalsDBDataSet();
sqlAdapter.Fill(sqlData);
string strCSVDataLine = "1,2,3,four"
sqlData.Tables[0].Rows.Add(new object[] { strCSVDataLine });
sqlAdapter.Update(sqlData);

sqlConnection.Close();
```

This code fails to work

How can I use C# to populate my database with the .csv data?

Is my method incorrect/incomplete?

Is there a better way to do this?

The reason I would like to use sql is because there is a lot of data. I could create a class structure to contain the data however it would also mean creating many different filter functions. Which SQL already contains...

Comment: do you get an error or does it just not give you what you expect?

Comment: It crashes. presumably because something isn't declared

Comment: To find error chuck in a try catch catch exception then output the caught info please then post it here

Comment: Update requires a valid InsertCommand when passed DataRow collection with new rows

Comment: OK now check the data inside the variable sqlData is what you expect

Comment: it is the adapter update line that causes the error

Comment: Yeah but you are feeding in the sql data so put a break point on the updater line and manually look to see if sql data has the data you expect.

Comment: I would if the debugger worked! however IT screwed up my installation of visual studio. Anyway ive stopped the error by adding the line: sqlData.Tables[0].Rows[0].AcceptChanges(); How can i view if the data has been succesfully added?

Comment: Download mysql and check the file using that is the way I would check it but others load the data using code then out put to a text file which they read in notepad.  If your visual studio isn't working correctly I would recommend getting it fixed if you are doing a lot of database work. Also another way to debug the sql data(only if needed in future) is write a function that generates a text file outputting the data member name then a gap then the data in that section and use a new line for each different one, then call that function just before the line that is breaking the the program.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67481/discussion-between-danaldo-and-zoomvirus).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problems were due to blank values occurring in the .csv file

This was my fix

```
public void Import(string csvfname)
{
    string password;
    string cacheDatabase;
    string connectionString;
    System.IO.StreamReader objFile;
    string strCommand;
    string lineHeader;
    string line;
    string[] arrLineData;

    cacheDatabase = new System.IO.FileInfo(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location).DirectoryName + "\\MyDatabase.sdf"; ;
    password = "";
    connectionString = string.Format("DataSource=\"{0}\"; Password='{1}'", this.cacheDatabase, this.password);

    objFile = new System.IO.StreamReader(csvfname);

    lineHeader = objFile.ReadLine();

    while (!objFile.EndOfStream)
    {
        line = objFile.ReadLine();
        arrLineData = line.Split(',');
        try
        {
            sqlConnection = new SqlCeConnection(connectionString());
            strCommand = "INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES ('" + arrLineData[0] + "', '" + arrLineData[1] + "', '" + arrLineData[2] + "')";
            SqlCeCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCeCommand(strCommand, sqlConnection);
            sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            sqlConnection.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error in Import(): " + exc.Message);
        }
    }
}
```